# Issue with Dice Roll command

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command '-dice  ' in which it then responds with a random number between number1 and number2. However, if they didn't put a number1 and number2 then it just does it between 1 and 6.

I have tried some code and it says that 'number1 and number2' is a required argument when it puts nothing. When I put numbers in, it says 'nil' is not defined.

```
import random
@client.command()
async def dice(number1, number2):
    if number1 == nil and number2 == nil:
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        print(f"The dice rolled a {number}!")

else:
    number = random.randint(number1, number2)
    print(f"The dice rolled a {number}!")
```

INPUT: -dice
OUTPUT: The dice rolled a

INPUT: -dice [number1] [number2]
OUTPUT: The dice rolled a [number between number1 and number2]

Comment: What is your `nil`? Why did you put it there?

Answer (score 0):

By `nil`, I'm assuming you mean `None`? If that's the case, I see you are trying to check if arguments `number1` and `number2` were passed into the function.

Luckily enough, you don't need to implement any logic, just change your function definition:

```
import random
@client.command() #-> not sure what this is meant to achieve
async def dice(number1=1, number2=6): #-> not sure why you have async here?
    number = random.randint(number1, number2)
    print(f"The dice rolled a {number}!")
```

Setting `number1=1` and `number2=6` in the definition basically means: 'we have two (optional) parameters for our `dice` function. If values for these parameters are not passed in when the function is called, set them to 1 and 6 respectively by default. If values for these parameters are supplied however, ignore the default values and use what was passed into the function call as the respective values.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the required behaviour of a default value (1 or 6 for example) you have to specify that inside the function definition, so you get something like this:

```
import random
@client.command()
async def dice(number1=1, number2=6):
    number = random.randint(number1,number2)
    print(f"The dice rolled a {number}!")
```

This way the default value (after the '=') is used when none is provided. In your initial code you require a `number1` and `number2` argument, so it crashes when none (or only one) are/is given.